# Attaching an artifact from pipeline run to a PR in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have pipeline in Azure where the build runs for a particular branch, for eg. `develop/test`. The build run generates an artifact which is a pdf file.

Is there a way to attach the latest artifact generated during the build pipeline automatically if there is a PR created from `develop/test` to `master` branch.

The YAML pipeline looks like below:

```
jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}

  variables:
    PIP_CACHE_DIR: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip

  steps:

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'pip | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
      restoreKeys: | 
        pip | "$(Agent.OS)"
      path: $(PIP_CACHE_DIR)
    displayName: "Cache pip packages"

  - script: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: "Install report tool dependencies"

  - script: |
      python report.py
    displayName: 'Running report tool'

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: 'report.pdf'
      artifactType: 'pipeline'
      artifactName: 'report'
    displayName: "Publish the report Artifact"
```

The pipeline is triggered when there is some edit on selected branch, for eg. `develop/*`

Comment: How does your build pipeline currently looks? Please share as much details as possible whether YAML/Classic editor based.

Comment: Thanks @Sibtain for your response. It is a YAML pipeline. I am running a python script in one of the tasks and then publish artifacts. The same aritfact is what I want to be attached in the PR automatically.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question with the same information including the YAML

Answer (score 0):

You may add attachments through the rest api. As example, PowerShell inline script (Add attachment to PR, Add link to the new attachment from the comments):

```
$user = ""
$token = '$(System.AccessToken)'

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"
$repoName = "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
$prId = "$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
$fileName = "YOU_FILE_NAME.EXT"
$localFilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/YOUR_FILE_PATH"
$bodyCommentTemplate = @"
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "parentCommentId": 0,
      "content": "[LINK_NAME](LINK_REF)",
      "commentType": 1
    }
  ],
  "status": 1
}
"@

$restAddAttachment = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pullRequests/$prId/attachments/$fileName`?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$restAddComment = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pullRequests/$prId/threads?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

function InvokePostFileRequest ($PostUrl, $FilePath)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -InFile $FilePath -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

function InvokePostRequest ($PostUrl, $PostBody)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $PostBody -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}


$resAttachment = InvokePostFileRequest $restAddAttachment $localFilePath 

$attachmentRef = "[$($resAttachment.displayName)]($($resAttachment.url))"

$attachmentRef

$bodyComment = $bodyCommentTemplate -replace "LINK_NAME", $resAttachment.displayName
$bodyComment = $bodyComment -replace "LINK_REF", $resAttachment.url

InvokePostRequest $restAddComment $bodyComment
```

As result:

[image]

You may use your PAT or Build Service. If build service, it should have permission `Contribute to pull requests` on your repo.